# Summing arrays using 2 variables in a loop(and running the loop N/2 times) gives faster runtime than just one. Why?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, gcc, optimization

I have an array of size SIZE. I am adding its elements in two ways.
1. Taking 2 variables in a loop, running one from index 0 and other from SIZE-1 till they intersect.
2. Taking 1 variable and running it from 0 to SIZE-1.
Why does the first method run considerably faster than the second one.

I am running it on GCC.
Only difference that I can see is the number of comparisons.

### Using 2 variable

```
long sum2ptr(int* x, long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = n-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        sum += x[i];
        sum += x[j];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This outputs 0.43

### Using 1 variable

```
long sum1ptr(int* x, long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += x[i];
    return sum;
}
```

This outputs 0.50

### Common code

```
int main(void)
{
    long SIZE = 100000000;
    double start, time = 0;
    int *a = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
        a[i] = ((i * 2) + 3) % SIZE;

    start = clock();
    sum2ptr(a, SIZE);//called sum1ptr() on second run.
    time += (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("%lf", time);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting negligible difference between the two. What is the actual reason behind such a drastic difference.

Comment: `sum2ptr` is totally different from `sum1ptr`. There is no reason why the execution time should only be slightly different.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you. Changes made as suggested

Comment: @Jabberwocky but in both of them number of sum operations are same, only difference is in number of comparisons. Does comparison make that big of a difference  (~16%) or is there something more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution time depends on the number of executed instructions. Instructions are for the memory access (a[i]), summation (sum+=a[i]) and loop management (I++, branch).

If the number of iterations is reduced, loop management is reduced and execution time accordingly. What you are considering is a special case of a classical code optimization method called "loop unrolling".

Here is a modified version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


#define profile(x, fn, n) {\
    start = clock(); \
    sum = 0; \
    fn(x, n); \
    time = (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; \
}

#define sum2ptr(x, n) {\
    for (int i = 0, j = n-1; i < j; i++, j--) { \
        sum += x[i]; \
        sum += x[j]; \
    } \
}


#define sum1ptr(x, n) {\
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) \
    sum += x[i]; \
}

#define sum3ptr(x, n) {\
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=4){               \
    sum += x[i]; \
    sum += x[i+1]; \
    sum += x[i+2]; \
    sum += x[i+3]; \
  } \
}

#define SIZE 100000000

int main(void)
{
    double start, time = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int *a = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
        a[i] = ((i * 2) + 3) % SIZE;

    profile(a, sum1ptr, SIZE);
    printf("%lf (regular)\n", time);
    profile(a, sum2ptr, SIZE);
    printf("%lf (unrolled twice)\n", time);
    profile(a, sum3ptr, SIZE);
    printf("%lf (unrolled 4)\n", time);

    return 0;
}
```

I have added a third loop, "unrolled" four times (in a more classical way).

Compiled with gcc -O
here are the results.

```
0.030777 (regular)
0.016292 (unrolled twice)
0.008050 (unrolled 4)
```

As you can see, unrolling is very effective. The results are even better than yours, because of the optimization (-O). Without optimization flags, we get

```
0.222738 (regular)
0.174113 (unrolled twice)
0.164410 (unrolled 4)
```

The differences are reduced and probably this is what you add done (but you should never measure performances without optimizing code).

Answer (score 1):

*sum1ptr* look at all the indexes, this is not the case for *sum2ptr* when *n* is odd, so of course they do not compute the same value

If I change a little your code to print the used indexes :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define sum2ptr(n) {\
    for (int i = 0, j = n-1; i < j; i++, j--) { \
        printf("sum2 %d %d\n", i, j); \
    } \
}

#define sum1ptr(n) {\
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) \
      printf("sum1 %d\n", i); \
} 


int main()
{
  sum2ptr(3)
  sum1ptr(3)

  return 0;
}
```

The execution is :

```
sum2 0 2
sum1 0
sum1 1
sum1 2
```

*sum2* do not look at the index 1.

If you access to 2 entries each turn the size must be an even number. If you look at 3 entries each turn the size must be a multiple of 3 etc

---

Concerning the speed there is no difference at all, and that doesn't surprise me, the code are identical except the error I already signaled.

If I compile in *O2* on *raspberrypi pi*, modifying a little your code to be able to choose the case depending on the presence of an argument (*argc* is 1 or 2), the result is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000011
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000009
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000009
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000013
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000014
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000008
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000012
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out 
sum1  0.000007
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out  1
sum2  0.000011
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out  1
sum2  0.000007
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out  1
sum2  0.000009
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out  1
sum2  0.000008
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out  1
sum2  0.000008
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out  1
sum2  0.000010
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out  1
sum2  0.000009
```

the difference of times are under the precision

Comment: Yes, I was just interested to know why sum2ptr() is taking less time; assuming size is even. It could be changed such that it looks at all indices, it still would take less time.

Comment: @HarshitSingh I don't know in which conditions you did your tests, but for me there is no real differences

Comment: I didn't use optimization of any kind (just ran `gcc file.c` ). I think optimizing it unrolls the loop.

Comment: No. gcc unrolls loops if it is explicitely required. Check what is done with gcc -Q -c -O3 --help=optimizers And without optimization, the generated code is a pure nonsense in terms of performances.